# Adding SQL Server Express to mvc 4 project

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.NET MVC 4, I am trying hard to connect to a SQL Server express database in my project. I am not getting it right. I have been researching this for many days.

I am not able to get the exact steps. So please provide me step by step procedure to connect my ASP.NET MVC 4 project to SQL Server Express

Comment: are you using EF 5.0 + ? how you are trying exactly . explain us a bit so we can assist you .

Comment: Ya i am using EF6. I am trying to create localDb. But i am unable to get it. i just want a nice and clean steps to add.

Comment: Have you looked at [http://www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net) - especially [Intro to MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4)?? It has **tons** of good walkthroughs, tutorials etc.

Comment: pretty basic mate . have you tried compact db 4.0 or sql db by adding new item under database .

Comment: I have my db ready, with all the related tables. I just need to connect it to perform some actions. i dint try compact db.:(.

Comment: So let me assume that you can see your tables in the Visual Studio SQL Server browser. Now, if you highlight the database, and take a look at the properties window, there's your connection string...

Comment: Is SQL Server insalled? Can you connect to it with management studio? If not that is not "I am new to asp.net mvc" (because mvc does not connect to databases) but "I never learned ado.net and basics, please point me to a BOOK".

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you get any error message while connecting or you do not know how to make the connection? If you are getting an error please share the error message, and if it is the later case then you might want to try creating a project in VS using the Internet Template for MVC. You will understand properly.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this link does help you to setup successfully .

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171890.aspx

or

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171890(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171890%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

as u r new to MVC 
I think u must go through the videos of following link,
he will teach u very well and in layman language

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pzwRwYlXMw&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v

please go through it once

you will learn allot

Thank you